# Input text box validation is not working in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

When I click to add a button with an empty value, empty value added in the list. Here I have attached a screenshot. I need validation for an empty value. My code is not working.

Error Output: https://prnt.sc/pk0hvt

**HTML:**

```
<form
    id="listadding-wrap"
    @submit="checkForm"
    action="#"
    method="post"
>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newName">
    <button class="addbtn" @click="addName">+</button>

    <ul class="teamlist">
        <li v-for="teamMember in teamMembers" v-text="teamMember"></li>
    </ul>
    <p v-if="errors.length">
        <b>Please enter the value to add</b>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</form>
```

**Vue JS:**

```
var teammember = new Vue({

    el: '#listadding-wrap',
    data: {
        errors: [],
        newName:'',
        teamMembers: ['']
    },
    methods: { 
        checkForm: function (e) {
            if (this.newName) {
                return true;
            }
            this.errors = [];

            if (!this.newName) {
                this.errors.push('Name required.');
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        },

        addName() {
            this.teamMembers.push(this.newName);
            this.newName = '';
        }
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added 2 event handlers, one at form @submit and another at button @click

Here in the above code, button click triggers first and the form submit

I've moved the logic to submit action instead of two separate events

Here is the working code

For codepen : https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/RwwRgqd

```
<form
    id="listadding-wrap"
    @submit="checkForm"
    action="#"
    method="post"
>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newName">
    <button class="addbtn">+</button>

    <ul class="teamlist">
        <li v-for="teamMember in teamMembers" v-text="teamMember"></li>
    </ul>
    <p v-if="errors.length">
        <b>Please enter the value to add</b>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</form>

var teammember = new Vue({

    el: '#listadding-wrap',
    data: {
        errors: [],
        newName:'',
        teamMembers: [],
    },
    methods: { 
        checkForm: function (e) {
          console.log(e);
            this.errors = [];

            if (!this.newName) {
                this.errors.push('Name required.');
            } else {
              this.teamMembers.push(this.newName);
              this.newName = '';
            }


            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },

});
```